# FileVault is not finishing

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, filevault

I enabled FileVault in OSX SnowLeopard, and chose to encrypt my home directory and use Secure Virtual Memory.
3 days have passed since I turned it on, and it's not finished yet. I am stuck on the "Working" indicator.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was solved by logging out and leaving the machine to encrypt the home directory overnight. Are you performing any other large disk copy or file I/O (such as watching a movie etc.?).

Comment: Good point. It *might* very well be REQUIRED, given the fact that Time Machine won't backup either when logged in? According to Apple: *Note: If you use FileVault, your Home folder is backed up only when you are logged out and the Mac is awake for a Time Machine backup cycle.* -- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427

Comment: FileVault logged me out immediately after choosing to use it.
I reset the machine after waiting for 3 days, and everything seems OK.